# Perl: append numbers from one file to strings of second file

Tags: string, perl, unicode, pattern-matching

I would like to append numbers attached to (Unicode) strings in one file, to matched strings in a second file. Somehow I can't wrap my head around how to do this. Here is what my two files look like.

File 1:

```
दौरा, 2
प्रोत्साहन, 1
प्रगति, 4
```

File 2:

```
दौरा
dorA

प्रोत्साहन
prua2ts3Ahan
prua2ts2Ahan
prua2tsAhan
prua2t2s3Ahan
prua2t2s2Ahan
prua2t2sAhan
prOts3Ahan
prOts2Ahan
prOtsAhan
prOt2s3Ahan
prOt2s2Ahan
prOt2sAhan

प्रगति
praGat2I
praGatI
pragat2I
pragatI
```

The desired result would look like this:

Output:

```
dorA, 2

prua2ts3Ahan, 1
prua2ts2Ahan, 1
prua2tsAhan, 1
prua2t2s3Ahan, 1
prua2t2s2Ahan, 1
prua2t2sAhan, 1
prOts3Ahan, 1
prOts2Ahan, 1
prOtsAhan, 1
prOt2s3Ahan, 1
prOt2s2Ahan, 1
prOt2sAhan, 1

praGat2I, 4
praGatI, 4
pragat2I, 4
pragatI, 4
```

I have a hash created from File 1 that has the strings as keys, and the numbers as values. Now its a matter of matching these keys in File 2, collecting all following lines after the match, and appending the values to those following lines. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the solution is correct. Now just translate it to code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;

open my $F1, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'file.1' or die $!;
while (<$F1>) {
    chomp;
    my ($word, $num) = split /, /;
    $hash{$word} = $num;
}

open my $F2, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'file.2' or die $!;
my $word;
while (<$F2>) {
    chomp;
    if (exists $hash{$_}) {
        $word = $_;
    } elsif ($_) {
        print "$_, $hash{$word}\n";
    } else {
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - incredibly simple solution. The `elsif` statement is the one I was missing. This basically remembers `$word` from the hash call in the `if` statement - correct? I was fumbling around with `$nextline = <>` and so forth to proceed to the next line, but I now realize that's not even necessary. One more question though: The first line of the output file does not contain any leading white space, but all other lines do contain a single leading white space. How come?

Comment: @SebastianSulger: Yes, correct. The whitespace might come from the input files - my output is identical to the one you gave.